# Importing Excel data into SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel

I have extracted the data from an Excel file into SSMS and tried the following code.

However, its not working. The table (order) on the left side is unknown to the SQL code

```
use order
select * from order
```

[image]

Comment: Please, provide more information. What is the error message? Can you find the order table after a refreshing table list in SSMS?

Comment: You should avoid reserved words.  In the meantime, you bracket Select * from [Order]

Comment: Try `use [order] go` `select * from [order]`

Comment: Here is a list of reserved words  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/reserved-keywords-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Perfect Engineers. Thank u very much

Comment: Naming a table the same as the database, which is also reserved word is just a bad idea. Change the names; that's the real solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Order is a reserved keyword. Using straight brackets avoids this issue.

```
USE [order]
GO
select * 
from [order]
```